# Replacement for UNO to run project on Ubuntu 14.04 or later OS

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-12.04, libreoffice, uno

One of the old project has been developed on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using Python 2.7 in backend, LibreOffice and UNO for report generation. 
Now that server has been upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. 
As UNO with Python 2.7 is not supported on 14.04 LTS and entire project can not be migrated to Python 3, need to find a replacement for UNO which will go along with python 2.7 and 14.04 LTS.
Please suggest the options...

Comment: Apache OpenOffice still uses Python 2.  But my recommendation is to find someone who can migrate the project to Python 3.  Software often requires such changes to keep current.

Comment: Note that debian is still shipping the LibreOffice pyUNO code in python2 and python3. https://packages.debian.org/sid/python-uno and https://packages.debian.org/sid/python3-uno but note that long term the python2 code might disappear. Additionally newer pyuno in LibreOffice makes the python bindings more pythonic so updating might make the code much more readable.